# Am I faster in the air or on the ground?

Tags: mario-kart-8

A new mechanic in Mario kart 8 is the hang gliders, which allow you to steer your character in the air after a big jump. For maximum speed, should I try to maximize air time, by aiming upwards or minimize air time by aiming downwards? Or is it faster to do neither, and stay level vertically?